# Spring nullable String Bean

Tags: spring, configuration, maven

I have a filtered configuration like so (using Maven for filtering):

```
<bean class="com.whatever.SomeClass">
    <property name="someString" value="${filter.prop.value}"/>
</bean>
```

Sometimes that string property needs to be null (for reasons I wont go into here), so I need a way to specify the property as null. Clearly if I filter with the property file value "null", the bean property will be the String "null" instead of actually null.

I am aware that I can create something like a NullableStringFactoryBean which can look for the string "null" and handle it appropriately.

My question is: Does Spring provide a mechanism to do this already or is there some better way I can go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`setNullValue`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html#setNullValue%28java.lang.String%29) method from the [`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) class and see if it helps given your situation.

> Set a value that should be treated as null when resolved as a placeholder value: e.g. "" (empty String) or "null".

**EDIT:** Since you are using Maven filtering and don't want to have two mechanisms (one done by Maven on the process-resources phase and later, at runtime, one done by Spring) I see only three options:

**1)** Use a "smart" setter as @Tomasz Nurkiewicz specified in his answer. This might have side effects though as you also mentioned and might become "to smart for one's own good".

**2)** Inject the value of the property by using a `FactoryBean<String>` as you demonstrated in the answer you added to the question (with Spring's "p-namespace" being a nice way of limiting the amount of XML you have to write to accomplish this).

**3)** (crazy idea) replace the entire property injection in the XML. That is, instead of having this:

```
<bean class="com.whatever.SomeClass">
   <property name="someString" value="${filter.prop.value}"/>
</bean>
```

Have this:

```
<bean class="com.whatever.SomeClass">
   ${filter.prop.value}
</bean>
```

Now, `filter.prop.value` instead of `null` or `someValidValue` can become some white space and 
`<property name="someString" value="someValidValue"/>`, respectively.

This has the disadvantage that your IDE will complain about an invalid XML (since `<bean>` tag does not allow character children, only elements). But if you can live with that....

I would personally go for number 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am using Maven to filter my configuration files. Someone else may be able to use this solution with Maven by Maven filtering the locations used in the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, but I cannot because I use my properties for filtering more than my Spring configuration and I dont want to have two mechanisms. This is a perfect answer if I was not using Maven for this. I updated the question to explain that I am using Maven.

Comment: @smp7d: edited my answer based on the updated question. See if it helps.

Comment: yeah, I'm going with 2 as well. Just for anyone who sees this answer...it should not be "p" namespace specific. You can inject using any configuration style.

Comment: @smp7d: you are right about the configuration. I saw your answer on the question and "p-namespace" just stuck to my mind for some reason. I've edited my answer to incorporate your comment. Thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
public void setSomeString(String value) {
  if(value == null || value.equals("") || value.equals("null")) {
    this.value = null;
  } else {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather not. This class will be used across projects/organizations. In other places this bean may not be configured this way and "null" may be the desired value. One way or another it goes a bit against convention and as we are not distributing source code, may be confusing.

Comment: value.equals("") is not great.  if using this try StringUtils.isBlank() or StringUtils.isEmpty().  StringUtils is an apache commons lang class.

Comment: *@smp7d*: True, personally I am against non-trivial setters, but I thought this might help you a bit. | *@DwB*: I am aware of this class and these utility methods, I just didn't want to introduce external dependencies in this simple code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case anyone was wondering how this is done with a FactoryBean...

```
public class NullLiteralResolvingStringFactoryBean implements
        FactoryBean<String> {
    private String value;

    @Override
    public String getObject() throws Exception {
        if (value == null || value.equals("null")) {
            return null;
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Config:

```
<bean id="someString" class="com.whatever.NullLiteralResolvingStringFactoryBean"
        p:value="${filter.someString}" />
```